# vscode: Create rich content similar to what is in the Release Notes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rich-text-editor

Visual Studio code has very nicely formatted release notes:

[image: vscode Release Notes]
I'd like to create files that look this nice.

How is this done for VSCode?  And, is it possible for me to generate a similar document (embedded images, formatting, hyperlinks) in VSCode?  Or, do they use a 3rd party tool?

Comment: This is using markdown, and the markdown preview tool. You can open any markdown file and use the command "Markdown: Open Preview" to get the same sort of document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the release notes are just markdown converted to html that is rendered in a webview. You can use the [built-in markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview) to view markdown content in this way

If you are writing an extension that needs to show nicely formatted content like this, use the [`vscode.previewHtml` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands#_working-with-the-html-preview). [This example extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/contentprovider-sample) provides an example of how to do this using `TextDocumentContentProvider`